# How can I do this in illustrator, I did this one a few months ago but totally forgot it now

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6, text-wrap, skew

I did this straight skewing on a text once in Adobe Illustrator, can't find out again that how I did it, can anyone help?[image: asking about the 'SWEET PIXEL' skewing effect]

Comment: Transform -> Distort?

Comment: You forgot there is a [tool called "shear"](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html).

Comment: @Alin there isn't any Distort in Transform in Adobe Illustrator,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **Rad Lexus** it was shear.

Select any object/text then goto **Object>Transform>Shear..**

Thanksd once again